# Can't select Pandas DataFrame by quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used Pandas qcut function to sort a column of values into quantiles but I can't filter the DataFrame by those quantiles, here goes an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [i for i in range(100)], columns = ['values'])
df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df['values'], q = 10)
```

This gives me this DataFrame:

[image: Dataframe]

But when I try to filter by some decile:

`df[df['bins'] ==  (-0.001, 9.9]]`

I get:
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Changing the interval to a string, like `df[df['bins'] ==  '(-0.001, 9.9]']` just returns me an empty DataFrame, so it doesn't help either. How should I go about this?

Comment: You must close `(` with `)`. Doing `( ... ]`  causes syntax errors.

Comment: @kazemakase do you mean ```df[df['bins'] ==  (-0.001, 9.9)]]``` or ```df[df['bins'] ==  (-0.001, 9.9])]```? Either way I get invalid syntax...

Comment: @kazemakase that fixes the syntax error but does not return the required result, see my answer below

Comment: @PranavHosangadi how is this not reproducible? ```range``` function does not even need an import, also the problem here wasn't caused by a typo. Not sure what your flagging is about...

Comment: @RodrigoMeireles Apologies, I misread your question. You have your answer already, but I voted to reopen in any case

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it is ok, I just got confused by the flagging. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pandas.qcut` method return a Categorical series with an `pandas.IntervalIndex`. To index into that series you need to query using `pandas.Interval`s:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [i for i in range(100)], columns = ['values'])
df['bins'] = pd.qcut(df['values'], q = 10)
df.loc[df['bins'] == pd.Interval(-0.001, 9.9)]
```

The reason you get a syntax error using `df['bins'] == (-0.001, 9.9]` is that Python expects brackets of the same type to match up. When printing the dataframe it does show exactly that sequence, because that matches the conventional notation, but it is just the string representation of the `pd.Interval` object that is actually in the dataframe.